# Массив строк как использовать в андроид разработке

Tags: java, android

Есть массив :

```
 final String[] texts = {"Математика","Музыка (Пение)","Изобразительное искусство (Рисование)","Английский язык","Казахский язык",
        "Немецкий язык","Китайский язык","История","География","Биология","Химия"}
```

Его использую очень часто  в моем приложений,как его сохранить один раз и вызывать с любого места

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переместите его в константы.

```
import ...;
import ...;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final String[] texts = {"Математика","Музыка (Пение)","Изобразительное искусство (Рисование)","Английский язык","Казахский язык", "Немецкий язык","Китайский язык","История","География","Биология","Химия"}
```

Вызывать по названию переменной `texts`. Например, чтобы в сообщении `Toast` показать второй элемент массива

```
Toast.makeText(this, texts[1], 0).show();
```

Тоесть, название массива `texts` и в квадратных скобках индекс (порядковый номер минус один). Например, если нужен первый элемент " Математика", то индекс будет `0`, и т.д.

А лучше вообще вынести массив в `res/values/array.xml` - будете готовы к локализации (не все же ваши пользователи знают русский)

```
<string-array name="texts">
  <item>Биография</item>
  <item>Русский Язык</item>
  <item>......</item>
  ...
</string-array>
```

А в коде `Activity`

```
String[] texts = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.texts);
```

**Удачи!**

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: Не "такая фишка .." , а индексы списков (в том числе и массивов) начинаются с нуля. Так почти во всех языках программирования и связано с практичностью применения при выборке данных. Индекс элемента - это смещение от начала списка, а не порядковый номер.

Comment: Спасибо, поправили :)